# warning: comparison between pointer and integer array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

These are parts of my codes.

```
struct identifier_structure
{
    char identifier[30] ;
};

char read [30];

struct identifier_structure identifier_list [30] ;     

if(strcmp(identifier_list[i].identifier,read) == 0 ||
     identifier_list[i].identifier == read[0])
```

Problem is warning: "comparison between pointer and integer".
Everything is in char type, Why am I taking pointer and integer comparison error?

Comment: why did you added this condition `identifier_list[i].identifier == read[0]` ?

Comment: I'm doing lexical analyze and I need to know read[0] could be equal or not

Comment: The error message says it all. You might like to read C primer.

Answer (score 4):

```
identifier_list[i].identifier==read[0]
```

The left operand of the `==` operator after conversion is of type `char *` and the right operand is of type `char`. You cannot compare pointers and integers in C.

Comment: Read is an array which including chars so Should read[0] be char ?

Comment: @gula93 `read` is an array of `char`, `read[0]` is the first element of the array and its type is `char`.